# Get all documents in a collection in PHP, Firebase

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the Cloud Firestore documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

I have copied this example:

```
$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$citiesRef->document('SF')->set([
    'name' => 'San Francisco',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'country' => 'USA',
    'capital' => false,
    'population' => 860000
]);
$citiesRef->document('LA')->set([
    'name' => 'Los Angeles',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'country' => 'USA',
    'capital' => false,
    'population' => 3900000
]);
$citiesRef->document('DC')->set([
    'name' => 'Washington D.C.',
    'state' => null,
    'country' => 'USA',
    'capital' => true,
    'population' => 680000
]);
$citiesRef->document('TOK')->set([
    'name' => 'Tokyo',
    'state' => null,
    'country' => 'Japan',
    'capital' => true,
    'population' => 9000000
]);
$citiesRef->document('BJ')->set([
    'name' => 'Beijing',
    'state' => null,
    'country' => 'China',
    'capital' => true,
    'population' => 21500000
]);
printf('Added example cities data to the cities collection.' . PHP_EOL);
```

And the request :

```
$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$query = $citiesRef->where('capital', '=', true);
$documents = $query->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
        printf('Document data for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
        print_r($document->data());
        printf(PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
    }
}
```

I can't go to the `else` block.
If I change `where('capital', '=', true)` to `where('capital', '=', 'test')`, the condition should be false and I enter the `else` block because the documents no 'does not exist.

But I have a blank page.
can someone explain to me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The query already returns only those documents in the collection that *do* match your query, that's why every document in the resultset exists.

- `$citiesRef->where('capital', '=', true);` returns only documents in which the field `capital` exists at all, regardless of the value (= all documents from the example dataset - documents without a `capital` field would not be returned)
- `$citiesRef->where('capital', '=', 'test');` returns only documents in which the field `capital` equals `test` (= no documents)

For that reason, you don't even enter the `if` condition: the returned document collection is empty.

The `$document->exists()` method is useful when you try to access a document by ID directly:

`$doc = $citiesRef->document('non-existing-document-id')` would still return a `DocumentReference` object, but here `$doc->exists()` would return false.

Long story short , you can remove the condition from the loop:

```php
$citiesRef = $db->collection('cities');
$query = $citiesRef->where('capital', '=', true);
$documents = $query->documents();

foreach ($documents as $document) {
    printf('Document data for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
    print_r($document->data());
    printf(PHP_EOL);
}
```

and try this to confirm that the `exists()` method works as expected:

```php
$doc = $citiesRef->document('test')->snapshot();

if ($doc->exists()) {
    printf('The document with ID "%s" exists.'.PHP_EOL, $doc->id());
} else {
    printf('The document with ID "%s" does NOT exist.'.PHP_EOL, $doc->id());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood!

Answer (score 0):

In your first condition,

- `where('capital', '=', true)`

it enters the `forEach` block since it returns few matching some documents. i.e) the length of the `$documents` is `> 0`

- `where('capital', '=', 'test')`

This wouldn't have entered into the `forEach` loop as no matching documents retrieved from firestore. i.e) the length of the `$documents` is `== 0`

So, before iterate over the `$documents` you have to check whether the retrieved `$documents` is empty or has any documents in it.

In JS, (as i don't know PHP)

```js
if (documents.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

documents.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

- calling the `exists()` useful, only when you retrieve a document by it's reference. If there is no document at the location referenced by `DocumentReference`, the resulting document will be empty and calling `exists()` on it will return false.